# Proposition: The union of two finite sets is finite. (proving without induction)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, set-theory, problem-solving, cardinals

Is my proof correct?

Notations:
$\mathbb{N}$:=$\{1,2,3,..
\}$ = The set of all natural numbers.

$J_q$:=$\{ y : 1\leq y \leq q, \text{ for some } q \in \mathbb{N}\}$ = The set of first $q$ natural numbers.

$|W|:=$ The cardinality of set $W$.

$ v:T \rightarrow U $ is read as '$v$ is a function from $T$ to $U$, where $T$ and $U$ are sets.'

Proof:

$$\begin{align}\text{Let }A \text{ and } B \text{ be any two finite sets. }\tag{1}\label{eq1}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\text{If } A=\varnothing \text{ and } B=\varnothing, \text{ then }A\cup B=\varnothing.\\
\text{If } A\neq\varnothing \text{ and } B=\varnothing, \text{ then }A\cup B=A.\\
\text{If } A=\varnothing \text{ and } B\neq\varnothing, \text{ then }A\cup B=B.\\
\text{If } A\neq\varnothing \text{ and } B\neq\varnothing \text{ such that } A=B, \text{ then }A\cup B=A=B.\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

$$\begin{align}\text{Now, let } A\neq B \text{ and } |A|=n, \ |B|=m \\ \text{ for some } n,m \in \mathbb{N}\tag{3} \label{eq3}\end{align}$$

We know that $A \cup B = A \cup (B/A)$

Let $f:J_n \rightarrow A$ such that $f(i):=a_i, \forall i \in J_n \ \implies f  $ is bijective.

Let $|B/A|=p$, for some $p \in \mathbb{N}$. Since, $B/A$ is a subset of $B$, we have $p\leq m$.

Let $g:(J_{n+p}\backslash J_n)\rightarrow (B/A)$ such that $g(n+j):=b_j, \forall j \in J_m$. $\implies g$ is bijective.

Let $h:J_{n+p}\rightarrow A \cup B $ such that

$$h(x):=\begin{cases}f(x), & \forall x \in J_n \\ g(n+x), & \forall x \in (J_{n+p}/J_n) \end{cases}$$

$$\because \ B/A \cap A = \varnothing \ \\ \implies f(\omega)\neq g(\lambda), \forall \omega \in J_n, \forall \lambda \in (J_{n+p}/J_n)$$

Let $\theta \in A \cup B$
$\implies \theta \in A$ or $\theta \in B/A$
$\implies \ \exists s \in \mathbb{N}, s\leq n \text{ such that }\theta=a_s$ or $\exists r \in \mathbb{N}, r\leq p \text{ such that }\theta=b_r$
$\implies \theta=f(s)=h(s)$ or $\theta=g(n+r)=h(r)$
$(\because f \text{ and } g \text{ are onto.})$

Thus, $h$ is onto $\implies |A\cup B|\leq |J_{n+p}|=n+p$
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}\implies \text{If } A\neq\varnothing \text{ and } B\neq\varnothing \text{ such that } A\neq B, \text{ then }  A\cup B \text{ is finite}\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

$(1),(2),(3),(4) \implies$ for any two finite sets, their union is always finte.

Comment: Okay, I will write it 

Comment: $|A\cup B|=|A| + |B|-|A\cap B|$

Comment: Is a *surjection* $J_{n+m}\to A\cup B$ (or an injection $A\cup B\to J_{n+m}$) not good enough to conclude finiteness?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, that's true. There is no need to show the injectiveness of h. Thanks for your input

Comment: @KevinShenoy I would suggest to write $B\setminus A$ instead of $B/A$, which could is somewhat confusion as the notation $B/A$ is used for the [quotient set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class).

Comment: @KevinShenoy What are the axioms you are allowing yourself?

Comment: @ZhenLin Axiom: If f:A->B is onto then |B|<=|A|, this one.

Comment: Is that the only one?? Please list all of them.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yup, as an axiom only one( but yes I am only considering ZFC w.r.t to this proposition and proof)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are probably overcomplicating things with your approach.  Don't worry about the overlap elements or if they are the same.  You can eliminate the empty set as you do to keep needing to worry about empty bijections (Though it wouldn't pose a problem)

By definition of being nonempty/finite,  you have a bijection $f:J_n\to A$ and $g:J_m\to B$ for some $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$.  Define $h:J_{n+m}\to A\cup B$ as $h(i)=f(i)$ if $i\leq n$,  otherwise $h(i)=g(i-n)$.
This is a surjection,  so by the one axiom you are using,  you have $|A\cup B|\leq |J_{n+m}|$,  hence finite.

Comment: Is it clear that a set that admits a surjection from a finite set is finite? (There are settings where this is not true.)

Comment: @Alan Your way of defining makes the proof much simpler. Thank you! (Yes, the trivial cases I just mentioned so that its all included )

Comment: @ZhenLin The OP included that surjection preserves order of cardinality (in the right direction) in comments as an axiom

Comment: @Alan I don’t think it is obvious. For your education, let me point out that in constructive mathematics it can happen that a set admits a surjection from a finite set but not itself be finite (= in bijection with a finite set).

Comment: @ZhenLin Would that setting include the axiom if $f:A\to B$ is a surjection then $|B|\leq |A|$ + ZFC?

Comment: No. That is not the point. The point is that you must be using some of your assumptions. What are those assumptions? For this question you cannot even assume ZFC per se because that would contradict the instruction to "not use induction".

Comment: @ZhenLin I was going with the OP's comments about what axioms to use.  Perhaps those should be edited into the question, and a comment could be made that induction is perhaps being used behind the scenes as part of that axiom.